# How VirtualBox NAT network is one-direction only?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-interface

When a VM in VirtualBox uses NAT networking, it is able to communicate with the host, but the host is not able to communicate with (e.g., ping) the VM.
How is it possible? Is it some iptables setup?

Looking at `ip a` of the VM I see `eth0 10.0.2.15/24`.
On my host, there is no interface in that network. Then, I wonder, how is communication even possible? And why it's one-direction only?

Another question, I think it's related (if not, let me know, I'll create another post):
On the host I have a docker container running, connected to the default docker0 bridge. Its IP is `172.17.0.2`. I want to ping it from the same VM that I mentioned above (Virtualbox, NAT). Since the VM also has docker installed, it also has the docker0 bridge with the same network CIDR as docker0 on my host. Then, I use the following ping:
`ping -I eth0 172.17.0.2`. This should force the traffic to go through VM's eth0, which, as I understand has a connection with my host (since I can ping my host freely). All the packets are lost. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the VM without configuring port forwarding for that virtual NAT network. The easy solution for problem is changing the network adapter to Bridged adapter.

If you change the mode of the network adapter, the VM will be like another device in your network and will be accessible.

I let you [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) the documentation about this topic and a little table to understand this:

" A virtual machine with NAT enabled acts much like a real computer that connects to the Internet through a router. The router, in this case, is the Oracle VM VirtualBox networking engine, which maps traffic from and to the virtual machine transparently. In Oracle VM VirtualBox this router is placed between each virtual machine and the host. This separation maximizes security since by default virtual machines cannot talk to each other.

The disadvantage of NAT mode is that, much like a private network behind a router, the virtual machine is invisible and unreachable from the outside internet. You cannot run a server this way unless you set up port forwarding."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that, I am mostly trying to understand how the NAT mode works "internally". How is it implemented by VirtualBox that the traffic is one direction only by default?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What did you not understand?

Comment: You're right! The documentation is actually surprisingly good in explaining how it works!